# How can I view the history of my voting, like upvotes?

Tags: support, voting, profile-page, activity-tab, history

Sometimes I want to return to some of the answers I have upvoted. Can I access the history of my votes?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work

Comment: If anyone come's here seeking more stats about votes for questions vs answers, and more, scroll down till the bottom of your activity tab, right above the footer at the right.

Comment: You can only do this for your own account. "The total vote count is public, but not what each person votes for. Voting is anonymous." -@gunr2171

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can see the history of your voting in your profile page. A direct link is available at https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=upvote (this link auto directs to the current user's profile page).

1. Go to your profile
2. Switch to the "Activity" section if it is not already selected
3. Click the "votes" tab
4. Choose the types of votes you would like to filter on, like "upvote"

Optionally: Select account under "Accounts" if you've joined multiple communities

[image]

Note that only *you* can view this page. It won't show up if you try to see the voting history of other users.

However, this shows all *posts* you have voted on. You can't filter by only answers.

Comment: Is this your own account or your sock-puppet? Where do you find stuff to up-vote? ;)

Comment: Is there any way I can see my history of votes on comments?

Comment: @MJGwater sorry, those stats aren't available

Comment: For the record - If you joined multiple communities, make sure select the  relevant account (community), before heading to the "votes" tab.

Comment: @TzunghsingDavidWong Good point, but how do I change communities while looking at my profile?

Comment: @ScottBiggs On the left-hand side of the profile page, right under your profile picture, you should find a list of communities you belong to.  What I usually do is clicking on the community name, then select the "profile".

Comment: The vote count is public, no point in blurring it?

Comment: @10Rep The total vote count is public, but not what each person votes for. Voting is anonymous. I guess, sure, I could have shown an unblurred picture (6 years ago when I took this), but the whole point is that only I know what I voted for.